# How to convert TBuf8 to QString

Tags: qt, symbian, type-conversion, descriptor, qstring

I've tried to convert using the following code:

```
template< unsigned int size >
static QString
TBuf82QString( const TBuf8< size > &buf )
{
   return QString::fromUtf16(
      reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(
         const_cast<TUint8*>(
            buf.Ptr() ) ), buf.Length() );
}
```

But It always returns something like `?????b`.

**EDIT: Changed code example**

Comment: Does that code above work if QT_NO_UNICODE is defined?

Comment: It does not even compile, it seems.

Comment: What is stored in your TBuf8? Are there really UTF16 characters in the correct byte order there? And is it terminated with 2 zero bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a template probably isn't a good solution, since it will result in a new instantiation of this block of code within your application binary, for every size of input string which is converted.  Since the output type (QString) contains no compile-time constant, this means you end up with code bloat, for no gain.

A better approach would be to leverage the fact that `TBuf8<N>` inherits from `TDesC8`:

```
QString TBuf2QString(const TDesC8 &buf)
{
    return QString::fromLocal8Bit(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buf.Ptr()),
                                  buf.Length());
}

TBuf<16> foo(_L("sometext"));
QString bar = TBuf2QString(foo);
```

Comment: This still outputs rubbish. I'm trying to convert the WLAN BSSID given by CConnMonWlanNetwork::WlanBssid() : TBuf8<KWlanBssId>. Good point about the template though.

Comment: Can you add more code? Maybe you're trying to display it incorrectly?

Comment: As James suggests, an 8-bit descriptor should be printed using `RDebug::RawPrint`, not `RDebug::Printf`

Answer (score 1):

`TBuf8` is used for binary data or non-Unicode strings. `TBuf16` is used for Unicode strings. `TBuf` is conditionally compiled and will always be `TBuf16` as Symbian OS is natively Unicode.

Try using `QString::fromLocal8Bit()` with `TBuf8::Ptr()`